# Is there a Graph API to list Target Domains under External Identities?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to access Target Domains via a Graph API, such as you can setup in Azure External Identities; see screenshot below. I've had a look at the Graph documentation, but no luck.

[image: Azure External Identities]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for Configure settings of external identities with Microsoft Graph:
[image].

Refer this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/external-collaboration-settings-configure#configure-settings-with-microsoft-graph).

Comment: I can see from the DOC (link) that you can manage the Target Domains using PowerShell, but there is no mention of GraphAPI; is it even possible (yet?) via Graph?

Comment: For example, getting the authorizationPolicy ofr guest user you we can "GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/authorizationPolicy". using the Graph API.